# Decent web based drawing platform?

Tags: web-apps, drawing

I would like to find a decent web based drawing platform and was wondering if you guys could help me out. Also not sure if web based is the right term, but basically I want to be able to use it on a chromebook without having to download anything from the chrome store or hacking the device. Not sure if this is on topic here but I think this is the best SE site for this.

Very minimal requirements;

- line tool
- circle tool
- text tool
- four different fonts
- able to edit and stuff offline
- no download or money required to draw(I am on chromebook)
- export/save as jpg and/or svg

Bonus points for;

- square/rectangle tool
- extra fonts
- export/save as pdf
- bold italic and underline choices for text
- grouping function similar to adobe illustrator

If you can find a pen tool similar to adobe illustrator anywhere than that would be a winner right there as long as it also has the very minimal requirements.

Anybody have any recommendations?

Comment: Not sure what specifically you want to draw – but maybe take a look at draw.io?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the suggestions that [Google offers for "online graphic editor"](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+graphic+editor)?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, no, but just because i was asking google the wrong question. good idea.